# aws share AMI then close instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, amazon-ami

I have an aws instance running on one account A. Then I wanted to transform everything on that account to another aws account B. Here's what i did, i create an AMI (private) for A and shared it with account B by adding permissions. Then I used the shard AMI created another instance running on account B.

Now is it safe to shut down the running instance on account A? Cause I no longer want to use that account.

Or what further steps do I need?

Thanks,it's really a hurry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's all the steps you need to do. Now you can safely remove the EC2 instance and the AMI from account A, account B won't be affected.

Comment: Thx! But why is that, I thought the AMI is some kind of back up image (or copy from the instance). It's totally independent from the instance it's build up from? Even all the packages or git repositories and installed libs are all copied and totally fine on B now? B now is running but I'm too afraid to shut down A.

Comment: An AMI composed by an snapshot and some configuration. When you launch an AMI you are creating a new EC2 from that image, and the snapshot is "copied" in a new EBS volume.

Comment: I don't create a snapshot or configuration. I basically just create an AMI and add the permission. Can I add the tags or configurations now ? Where should I check? Thx!

Comment: Again: you can safely delete account A now.